# I am trying to convert the image tikz code

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Is it possible to create the picture shown below in Tikz? I am fairly new to this software and any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

I started with the below code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (a) [draw, matrix of math nodes, nodes={draw, anchor=center},
row sep=1mm, column sep=1mm]{%
\bullet & \bullet & \circ\\
\circ & \bullet & \circ\\
\circ & \circ & \bullet\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: I tried using a matrix of nodes but I couldn't put the small square boxes within the image.

Comment: \documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (a) [draw, matrix of math nodes, nodes={draw, anchor=center},
row sep=1mm, column sep=1mm]{%
\bullet & \bullet & \circ\\
\circ & \bullet & \circ\\
\circ & \circ & \bullet\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Comment: @MuzafarWani Please add this code to your question. As you can see, comments don't support linebreaks

Comment: @MuzafarWani, for your inspiration: 1) here is an example using matrix and various shapes https://texample.net/tikz/examples/node-shapes/ . 2) This one modifies arrows: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/double-arrows/ . // As you can see, tikz is quite a powerful chameleon.

Comment: A `matrix` is like any other node, then you can put `Data` and `Visit` with ` \node[draw, minimum size=..., right=of a] {Data \\ filtering};` and `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` in the preamble.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is the double border nodes, a possible solution could be to use a `label` for the inner part.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    inner/.style={draw, fill=orange!40, minimum size=5mm},
    outer/.style={draw, fill=pink!40, minimum size=8mm}]
\matrix (a) [draw, matrix of math nodes, nodes={outer, anchor=center},
row sep=1mm, column sep=1mm]{%
|[label={[inner]center:\bullet}]| & |[label={[inner]center:\bullet}]| & |[label={[inner]center:\circ}]|\\
|[label={[inner]center:\circ}]| & |[label={[inner]center:\bullet}]| & |[label={[inner]center:\circ}]|\\
|[label={[inner]center:\circ}]| & |[label={[inner]center:\circ}]| & |[label={[inner]center:\bullet}]|\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]